# Consider $f:[0,5] \rightarrow \mathbb {R}: x \rightarrow x^2$.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $P_n := [0= x_0, x_1, ... , x_{n-1}, x_n = 5]$, $x_k= \frac{5k}{n}$. Compute L(f,$P_n$).

For reference, this is from Abbot's Understanding Analysis, 7.2.2, we have a different function.

I know how to find the $x_k - x_{k-1}$ from the book, I am just a little stuck on calculating $m_k$, which is the infinum of the function for $x \in [x_{n-1}, x_n]$. I know it is the infinum of the function within each smaller interval in the partition, which leads be to believe that for $x \in [x_{n-1}, x_n]$, the infinum will be $x_{n-1}^2$. Would this imply I would use the same formula for $x_k$ to find the function's infinum?

Comment: You are omitting some details that makes this hard to answer. What even is $m_k$?

Comment: I edited the above response, my bad.

Comment: There still seem to be mistakes in your question; I feel like you mean to say that $P_n$ is the set of all the intervals $[x_i,x_{i+1}]$ with $i \in \{0,...,4\}$ and $x_i = 5i/n$

Comment: What the heck does $[0=x_0,x_1,...,x_{n−1},x_n=5]$ mean?

Comment: What the heck does $[0, \frac 5n, \frac {10}n, .... ,\frac {5n-5}n, 5]$ mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f $ is increasing at each $[x_k,x_{k+1}] $ thus

$$m_k=\inf_{[x_k,x_{k+1}]}f=f (x_k)=x_k^2$$

thus

$$L (f,P_n)=\frac {5}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}x_k^2$$

$$=\frac {5}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(\frac {5k}{n})^2$$

$$=\frac {125}{n^3}(1+4+9+... (n-1)^2) $$

$$=\frac {125}{n^2}\frac {(n-1)(2n-1)}{6} $$

The exact value is
$$\int_0^5 x^2dx=\frac {125}{3}$$
When $n\to+\infty $, we get the exact value.

Comment: Would I use the same intervals to calculate $U(f,P_n)$?

Comment: @Sam$$ M_k=x_{k+1}^2$$

Comment: @Sam The numerator will be $(n+1)(2n+1) $$